Are we supposed to ask Linux Mint questions here?
I understand Mint and Ubuntu are different distributions, but I've heard Mint described as Ubuntu based. Where is the best place to ask Mint questions?

On the Mint forums.

Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Lots of distros are "Ubuntu-based." Since we don't track their customizations and other changes, we don't answer questions about them. They are off-topic.

Np and even this question should be asked elsewhere: on META. Ubuntu Cinnamon is fine though ;)

Linux Mint has two products, one is Ubuntu based, the other is Debian based... Neither Linux Mint products are the same as their upstream sources, as the include changes and additional software (runtime adjustments) that tweaks the behavior of the code that Linux Mint cannot change (as it was packaged by upstream sources out of their control) making the system similar, but also rather different in many ways. Use your Linux Mint support & don't forget the differences in your system to either Ubuntu or Debian depending on which Mint you're using.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

FYI:   I am using a Ubuntu system, Ubuntu oracular, but I'm not allowed to use this site either; as my release is a development system and thus won't be on-topic on this site until it's released as Ubuntu 24.10 later this year (where I'll be moving to 25.04 anyway).  Consider the support options for your system before you download & install the product if you're likely to need support...

As Artur, guiverc, mook765 and Rinzwind have all pointed out the official place to ask questions related to Linux Mint is not here. There are however a few other good choices:

Linux Mint Forums: You can either use the static Mint Forums, linked with this bullet point, or use the official Mint chat room...
Unix and Linux: A Stack Exchange site where Mint is on topic (but, as always, have a good look at the allowed topics on this site before posting).
SuperUser: Another Stack Exchange site which does not bar Mint questions. Again have a look at their policy on allowed topics here before posting there...

So Mint support is not given on Ask Ubuntu and the canonical page where this is documented is here:

What topics can I ask about here?: Be aware that this is a page whose contents are decided on by Community consensus and the page itself can be directly edited by the elected Moderators of Ask Ubuntu following any change or further developments in that consensus.

